# How can I run external js file from child theme in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using wordpress and I have some custom js in an external file in the root of my child theme. I want the reference to this js file written to the very end of the html document just before the closing body tag. I first tried hardcode the reference into footer.php. I verified that the reference to the external js file was correct in the html source but the javascript did nothing, and also did not throw any errors in firebug. The external file contained only:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    alert('hello')
});
```

So after googling this problem for a while I found that I will need to use

```
wp_register_script
```

and

```
wp_enqueue_script
```

I found documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) but I am not very familiar with php...

Currently, I have added:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_javascript_files');
function load_javascript_files() {
    wp_register_script('scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . 'wp-content/themes/maya_child/scripts.js', array('jquery'), true );
    wp_enqueue_script('scripts');
}
```

to my child theme's functions.php file. The result is that the reference to my custom scripts file does not print out in the source at all

Am I maybe missing a step, or have I screwed up the php? Do I need to add something to header.php? or footer.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably the path to your javascript that's causing the problem. 
[get_template_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) returns the path to your theme rather than the path to your site. Also, when you're using a child theme, this function still returns the uri of the parent theme - so it's not the best choice here.

Instead try [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri):

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_javascript_files');
function load_javascript_files() {
    wp_register_script('scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script('scripts');
}
```

Note that neither of those functions returns a trailing slash on the uri, so you need to add that before the rest of your path eg. '/scripts.js'

Comment: ... and check the console to make sure it's loading.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson - I forgot to mention that... it is failing to load unless hardcoded. And if I hardcode it it fails to run besides being poor practice.

Comment: @James Wadington: Thanks! that did work. Oddly, it is not the last script reference before the </body> tag but perhaps some of the other script references are also being told to appear last and are overriding it.

Comment: Glad it helped. If you need to make sure specific files load first, you can add them to your dependencies alongside jquery.

Comment: @HelloWorld You could also use priorities to set the load order of scripts which have the same dipendencies. eg: `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_javascript_files', 5);`